# UV islands appear as small dots on map

Tags: uv

When I unwrap one by one object in my scene, everything is ok.

However, when I select them all, and then unwrap, most of my objects appear just as tiny dots on map and take very little space. First asociation is that scale is not applied but it is. Everything is merged by distance so there should not be overlapping vertices.

When unwrapping as Angle Based it seems ok, when unwrapping Conformal it is weird.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, here is what your file show, it looks normal except there are some overlapping faces: https://zupimages.net/up/22/44/57rh.jpg

Comment: That's with angle based I think? I mean, I can wrap it as angle based, no problem, but I used to unwrap hard surface as conformal, and this is the first time I face this problem.
I uploaded screenshots of the problem in my question now.